# Ajax FileUpload fails in Android native Browser (Webkit 534.30)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax, upload

I use the following code to upload a file exported from a canvas to a server. It works fine with Chrome for Android, but the upload fails with the native Android browser with webkit version 534.30.

```
var canvas; // a canvas with an image jpg or png
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
var file = dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl); //source: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob


                    var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("image", file);
        var xhrNativeObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Upload progress listener
        xhrNativeObject.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                var xhrPercentComplete = (position / total * 100 | 0);
                console.log(xhrPercentComplete, position, total);
            }
        }, false);

        xhrNativeObject.open("post", url, true);
        xhrNativeObject.onload = function (event) {

            var targetResponse = event.currentTarget;
            if ((targetResponse.readyState == 4) && (targetResponse.status == 200)) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(targetResponse.responseText);
                console.log(obj);
            } else {
                console.log("error");
            }

        }

        // send the file
        xhrNativeObject.send(formdata);
```

The file is alway empty when it reaches the server.

**How can I upload a file which is exported from a Canvas on Android native browser?**

Comment: @RayNicholus The file is alway empty when it reaches the server.

Comment: This is a bug in Android's stock browser.  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1146